# Multicollinearity for Offset Variable?

Tags: multicollinearity, count-data, poisson-regression, offset

In a Poisson model, do we need to check for multicollinearity between the offset variable and other covariates? For example, if I offset by population size, would it be problematic to include covariates that are correlated with population?

Comment: It is not problematic. In most software packages, the offset is specified *inside of* a function. In R, for example, `glm(y ~ x + offset(log(population))...)`, where population size is the offset/exposure variable.

Comment: **NO**. For an extreme example, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/306494/can-a-variable-be-used-both-as-an-offset-and-an-independent-variable

Answer (score 2):

No. In a count model, the offset/exposure variable is *not* a covariate. Rather than being estimated as a coefficient, its value is constrained to equal 1. It allows you to model *rates* instead of counts. I would review this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175349/in-a-poisson-model-what-is-the-difference-between-using-time-as-a-covariate-or) for more information.

Incorporating additional predictors that may be correlated with population size should not concern you if you're using *population* as your offset.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! I appreciate your clear response.